# How can I determine a Stata file's ds_format from the command line?

Tags: stata

I threw together this Perl one-liner to determine the Stata "ds_format" of some files...

`for file in *.dta; do perl -MParse::Stata::DtaReader -e 'open my $fileHandle, "<", @ARGV; my $dta = new Parse::Stata::DtaReader($fileHandle); print "$ARGV[0] is in STATA ds_format " . $dta->{ds_format} ,"\n\n";' $file; done`

... but I assume there's a way to use the command line `stata` command to get the same information. Is there? The script above prints for my files:

> study1a.dta is in STATA ds_format 113
>
> study1b.dta is in STATA ds_format 115
>
> study2.dta is in STATA ds_format 115

See also:

- http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?dta_113
- http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?dta
- http://search.cpan.org/dist/Parse-Stata-DtaReader/
- http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/foreign/html/read.dta.html

Comment: I hoped that someone had the answer (you can run Stata in batch mode, but I can't find a command the yields `ds_format`). Try the Statalist; it is very active. http://www.stata.com/statalist/

Comment: Could you use shell to run this Perl script?

Answer (score 1):

For now you can just read the first character of the file to determine the version. Beyond version file format version 117 (current for Stata 13), the version will be stored in the XML, so this method will have to be enhanced.

```
file open fhandle using dataset.dta, read binary
file read  fhandle %1s firstbytechar
file close fhandle
if "`firstbytechar'"=="<"{
    di "Version 117"
}
else {
    mata: st_numscalar("v", ascii("`firstbytechar'"))
    di "Version " v
}
```

Comment: The above has worked well for me. I use it when working with datasets that may have been saved in Stata 12 OR 13 (and with colleagues using Stata 12 or 13) to create flexible do files. I add ``if "`firstbytechar'"=="<" & c(version) == 13`` to get an if else command that can do either `use13` or `use` depending on file and user.